# Is it possible to submit not sandboxed app to the Mac App Store

Tags: macos, applications, applescript, mac-appstore, cocoa

I have an AppleScript Cocoa application that does a lot of shell scripts like `kill` or `chflags`. Is there any way I can try to send it on review to MAS and get it approved?

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_App_Store):

> Disallowed types of applications revealed by Apple include new apps
>   that are not sandboxed (as of June 1, 2012). At WWDC 2013, Apple
>   announced that this rule no longer applied, and that so-called
>   "temporary exceptions" may be used when the app has a reason not to be
>   sandboxed.

However, [Apple OS X Developer](https://developer.apple.com/osx/distribution) website states that sandboxing is required for Mac App Store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this it is possible but with caveat.

[App Sandbox Temporary Exception Entitlements](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/AppSandboxTemporaryExceptionEntitlements.html)

> Note: This chapter describes property list keys specific to the OS X
>   implementation of App Sandbox. They are not available in iOS.
>
> A temporary exception entitlement permits your OS X app to perform
>   certain operations otherwise disallowed by App Sandbox.
>
> If you need to request a temporary exception entitlement, use Apple’s
>   bug reporting system to let Apple know what’s not working for you.
>   Apple considers feature requests as it develops the OS X platform.
>
> Note: If you request a temporary-exception entitlement, be sure to
>   follow the guidance regarding entitlements provided on the iTunes
>   Connect website. In particular, use the Review Notes field in iTunes
>   Connect to explain why your app needs the exception, and include the
>   bug number.
>
> To request a temporary exception entitlement for a target in an OS X
>   Xcode project, add it to the target’s .entitlements property list file
>   using the Xcode property list editor.